# Switch from NIS/NFS to LDAP/NFS/SMB?

Tags: ldap, nis

I'm interested in moving from an NIS/NFS server (Ubuntu) to an LDAP/NFS/SMB on an Xserve. I've been able to get LDAP and the file sharing working, but now I'd like to actually import the existing user data.

How can I import the user accounts from the NIS server into OpenDirectory on the Xserve? Afterwards would rsync be the best way to transfer everyones directory from the existing NFS server to the Xserve while maintaing ownership and permissions?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [PADL's migration tools](http://www.padl.com/OSS/MigrationTools.html), and rsync should be fine.